# Extra HTML CSS being added upon theme change in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I mightve framed my question wrong but when I change my theme on material UI again and again, a few lines of HTML and Css are being added upon every change.
My code to change theme is

```
const [darkMode, setdarkMode] = useState(true);

  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: darkMode ? "dark" : "light",
    },
  });
  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setdarkMode(!darkMode);
  };
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
   <Typography
          className={classes.mainTitle}
          variant="h2"
          onClick={handleThemeChange}
        >
          Some text
        </Typography>
    </ThemeProvider>
```

This is what happens when I change theme

[image: Extra HTML add]

Comment: It can be added because many items change inside the library. What is the problem? Does it affect your code?

Comment: @Sowam it doesnt affect my code, but seemed worrying so asked it up!

Comment: If it doesn't affect your code that's fine :) don't worry

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-snowflake-6y71c

didnt see that happening over here tho, so was v curious to know :)